# CKEditor5 Inline build puts a p tag inside of an h1 tag - how do I disable this?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to make an h1 tag editable.

My HTML is

```
<h1 id="theh1">
    Hello how are you?
</h1>
```

And my JS is

```
e = document.getElementById("theh1");
InlineEditor
    .create( e,{
        removePlugins: [ 'Heading', 'Link' ],
        toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ]
      } )
      .catch( error => {
          console.error( error );
      } );
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r66uhfee/3/

If you view source, you see that the `h1` tag has a `p` element inside after editing it. How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, CKEditor 5 doesn't support this out of the box yet. This functionality is described in the [Allow enabling all types of editors on paragraph-like root](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/762) ticket.

However, this feature is potentially very easy to add. The crucial line of code is in every editor creator and looks like this:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/blob/d46af9fe4627da3f2f0b29349b1cbdabdf550637/src/classiceditor.js#L74:

```
this.model.document.createRoot();
```

The [`createRoot()`](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-createRoot) method is called with its default values so it always creates a root called `$root` which by the [schema](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_schema-Schema.html) is configured to only allow blocks (like paragraphs and headings).

If you'd create a root called `paragraph`, then that root would only allow text inside it and the editor would stop creating paragraphs:

```
this.model.document.createRoot( 'paragraph' );
```

Another thing that you might need to fix is that, in this particular case, some features may depend on this `paragraph` being marked as a [limit element](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_schema-Schema.html#function-isLimit) in the schema, so, in a specific editor which is enabled on a paragraph-like element, it'd be also good to do this:

```
editor.model.schema.extend( 'paragraph', { isLimit: true } );
```

However, we haven't tested this and we haven't designed the proper automatic solution for it, that's why the ticket is still open. So – the framework should allow this, but the implementations don't consider such case yet.

Comment: Hello...I know this is from a year ago. I'm trying to implement this but I am still confused. I tried to add this line but it did not allow me to create an already existing root "paragraph". So I tried extending the InlineEditor class and overriding the constructor, but new issues popped up then (I see `ElementReplacer is not defined`). Is there something step-by-step I can follow?

Comment: As I am writing this comment after 2 years of question asked. Can anyone who belongs to this conversation confirm that is it yet supported or not? I am also getting same problem and not able to fix it.